"Soft delete" in Hibernate with OneToOne mapping
I'm using a pattern called "soft delete". Instesd of deleting entity I just mark it as deleted and prevent it from showing up in results of any query by adding @Where(clause = "rmv = false")(rmv is name of colum in database where I store the flag).
In one scenario this approach do not work.
Here is example:
@Entity
@Table(name = "main_entity")
public class MainEntity {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "main", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private DetailEntity detail;
}
 
@Entity
@Table(name = "detail_entity")
@Where(clause = "rmv = false")
public class DetailEntity{
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private Boolean rmv = false;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "main_id", nullable = false)
    private MainEntity main;
}

When I try to get instance of MainEntity from Hibernate with mainEntityRepository.findById(id) I'm getting entity with detail != null. Despite the fact that ther record in detail_entity table have rmv = false.
It produce following SQL query
select m.*, d.* 
from main_entity m 
left join detail_entity d 
    on m.id=d.main_id 
where m.id=?

I expect it to have d.rmv=false condition in where clause.
My questions are:

Is it a bug or expected behavior?
If this is expected behavior is there any way to achive desirable effect?

EDIT
Hibernate version: 6.1.7

Where is the @Where annotation?

@DavidConrad I forgot to copy it. Thanks for noticing. I edited my question.

This problem is solved in newer version of hibernate.
I checked and 6.5.2 works fine.

Add the where clause to the parent (MainEntity) OneToOne Mapping as well.
@Entity
@Table(name = "main_entity")
public class MainEntity {

@Id
private Long id;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "main", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@Where(clause = "rmv = false")
private DetailEntity detail;
}


Unfortunately it doesn't affect generated SQL.
